# boost::condition_variable thread safety?

Tags: thread-safety, boost-thread

[This boost example on condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) shows that the mutex does not have to to held during the call to `cond.notify_one()`.  Does this imply that `boost::condition_variable` is thread-safe?  i.e. what happens if the "prepare data" thread releases the mutex and attempts to call `cond.notify_one()`, while the other thread now acquires the released mutex and simultaneously attempts the call to `cond.wait(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example does not imply that `boost::condition_variable` is thread safe.  Nevertheless, `wait`, `wait_for`, `wait_until`, `notify_one` and
`notify_all` are thread safe member functions.

Boost.Thread documents its [conformance and extension of the C++11 standard Thread library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/compliance.html#thread.compliance.cpp11).  It lists Condition variables, Class `condition_variable`, and Class `condition_variable_any` to be in compliance.

The relevant part of the standard (§ 30.5-2) states:

> Condition variables permit concurrent invocation of the `wait`, `wait_for`, `wait_until`, `notify_one` and `notify_all` member functions.